# How to do Flyway deployments in multiple stages

Tags: database, deployment, flyway

We are using Flyway successfully on a number of applications and now we need to run some of them in multiple stages:

1. Run database clean up scripts (truncate tables, etc.)
2. Do some deployment steps
3. Run other database scripts (schema changes, insert new data, etc.)

The first step is likely to be needed on multiple releases so we could mark it as a repeatable migration instead of as a normal one. However it shouldn't be run on all releases, only when it is needed.

Do you know how can this be done please? I assume we can first run the repeatable migration scripts, then add the other scripts to the migration folder and run the second migration step.

- Can we choose when to run those repeatable migrations? E.g. providing a flag or a specific folder?
- Would Flyway complain if we modify those repeatable scripts? E.g. if we want to add more columns/tables to the clean up scripts. We may be able to solve it by running a repair command.
  Thanks

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_,

Answer (score 0):

Repeatable migrations are only run again if their checksum has changed since they were last applied. The checksum is calculated from the file content, so you trigger a repeatable migration to be re-applied by changing it. This includes placeholder values, so for example a repeatable migration containing the `${flyway:timestamp}` placeholder will always be re-applied because it's value is constantly changing.

- By including `${flyway:timestamp}` in the repeatable migration (e.g. in a comment) it will always be re-applied if it's found, but you could control when this happens by storing it in a separate folder which is only configured when you want the it to run.

To include the repeatable migration:

```
./flyway migrate "-locations=migrations,repeatable_migration"
```

To exclude it:

```
./flyway migrate "-locations=migrations" "-ignoreMissingMigrations=true"
```

- This means you can modify the Repeatable script without causing any problems since the checksum is changing anyway - no need to run `repair`.